# Yii how to get Data from Count and Group By

Tags: yii

How to get an array by Executing this query in Yii?

```
SELECT `sevrity_id`,COUNT(*) FROM `Incident` GROUP BY `sevrity_id`
```

I need an array like this: `array(1=>20,2=10,3=12)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function getSevrityCounts()
{
    $data = array();
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT sevrity_id,COUNT(*) AS num FROM Incident GROUP BY sevrity_id');
    foreach($command->queryAll() as $row) {
        $data[ $row['sevrity_id'] ] = $row['num'];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: This is working, But searched for a method to get those data by model.
ex: using CDbCriteria and findAll or what ever....
any way Thanxx...

Comment: Why not just put it into a method inside a model then?